# Can i replace a string in a page with selectbox unique id using by php?

Tags: php, jquery, string, replace

Hello i'm trying to change a string value replace with selectbox.
So there are my codes. It shows what i want to do.

These are codes that i want to change.

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="a1">{box}</div>
  <div id="a2">{box}</div>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <div id="b1">{box}</div>
  <div id="b2">{box}</div>
</div>
```

can i replace as shown at below:

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="a1"><select id="a1_box">...</select></div>
  <div id="a2"><select id="a2_box">...</select></div>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <div id="b1"><select id="b1_box">...</select></div>
  <div id="b2"><select id="b2_box">...</select></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. http://php.net/dom

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jQuery -

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var currentText = $(this).text();

    if('{box}' == currentText){
        var newID = $(this).attr('id') + '_box';
        var newHTML = '<select id=' + newID + '></select>';
        $(this).html(newHTML);
    }
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8v14o1mw/)

Comment: Not exactly worked but it is show me a way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can . See the below code .

```js
function convert(){

  $(".box").each(function(){
    var id=$(this)[0].id;
    var select='<select id="'+id+'_box"><option>item</option></select>';  
    $(this).html(select); 
 });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" >
  <div id="a1" class="box">{box}</div>
  <div id="a2" class="box">{box}</div>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <div id="b1" class="box">{box}</div>
  <div id="b2" class="box">{box}</div>
</div>
<button onClick='convert()'> convert</button>
```